# Preventing user to click the Refresh Button of the Browser using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a asp.net web application where there is an iframe inside a dialog. I already disabled the f5, ctrl+f5, esc, and back button. I only tried the message popping up if the user reloads the page but that's not enough.
My client requirement is to not allow any user to Click the reload button of the browser.

1. Is there anyway to disable browser reload button? (all my searches said it's not possible)
2. Is there anyway to prevent the user from moving the cursor outside of a div/iframe?
   2.1. Is there a way to force the mouse pointer to go or set position? (My Idea is if the mouse pointer move to coordinate x1 & y1 it will be forced to move at the the coordinate x2 & y2)
3. Is there anyway to prevent the user to hover at the top of the browser which where the reload button bar?

Thanks in advance! Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Turn back on the f5 thing and just tell the client how bad an idea it is. Don't always listen to the client, they usually appreciate valuable feedback. How would you like it if the only way to escape stack-overflow is by restarting your computer? And your research is right, you can only ask for an "Are you sure you want to leave this page".

Comment: Thanks @René for your input. Already told them that, but instead they said the least I can do is to prevent the user mouse pointer to go to the top of the browser(reload button section). Do you have any suggestions? I will much appreciate it.

Comment: Just re-affirming what @René mentioned above. However, there are cases when this is a perfectly fine requirement. Especially if it is an intranet application with strict security policies. Make sure you never do that for an internet application.

Comment: People who override expected default browser behaviour deserve a special place in hell

Comment: @Leo Yes, they required it because there is a pop-up appearing after a payment. And if that pops up and the closes it the process will be messed up.

Comment: @AdrianBrand I agree with you,

Comment: I accept you plea of my client is a retard

Comment: @E.Saints that's not a valid reason to disable default browsers behaviour

Comment: @Leo For an intranet application where this should be prevented I would suggest a customised browser container app, running it as separate window will be so much clearer for everyone(but maybe there is a valid exception and I just didn't see it yet). E.Saints, All payment providers I know handle unexpected closing of the browser anywhere in the process just fine, so the same should be doable for your app. Maybe that's the the thing you should try finding an answer for?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<body onkeydown="return (event.keyCode != 116)">  
    <h1>  
        Test
    </h1>  
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Sir @CRR, thank you for your answer, but this only disable the f5 key which I already did. Do you have any suggestions on how can I disable/ not allow the user to use the reload button of the browser?

Comment: ohh okay , to disable browser button am not sure at the moment but will paste it if anything works for me